# optimal video quality using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg library in flutter. My task is to upload video captured with phone camera with the least Megabyte data possible while achieving quality which a human eye cannot feel.

I really need you suggestions on this. I tried this configuration,but I need more optimal if possible:

```
await _flutterFFmpeg.execute(
  "-i ${fileSystemEntity.path} "
  "-vcodec libx264 "
  "-crf 27 "
  "-preset ultrafast "
  "-an "
  "-y $newFilePath",
);
```

I need to reduce 2 min video below 10Mb if possible.

Comment: crf value 17 or 18 is considered visual lossless. Use a different (slower) preset if the file gets to big. See for more info the H264 video encoding guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: There is no such thing as "optimal" Only trade offs. (Thats said "ultrafast" provides the worst image quality for the highest bitrate) More CPU = smaller files.